# Preventing from part of files loading to browser

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular

Lets say i have login screen(model,controller,view) and few other screens (model,controller,view) that perform some secret manipulation that available only to logged in user.

Is this possible to load to browser only login files(That those files won't be shown in F12/sources) ,then when user successfully logged in load all the secret files.

In short i don't want that user can see those files before he logged in.

Answer (score 0):

That is one of the problems within client-side applications like angular SPAs. Since you want to load the content from your server, IF something happens on the client, the client already has to know, where it can get the content.

One solution could be to us ui-router. ([Documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)). There, you can set a state for logged in users. Every state can have an own html template, which gets loaded, when you enter the state. 
The problem ist, that the path of said html template is already on the client. That means, you have to set some kind of cookie from your server, so that you know, that the client is logged in. And only then, the requested template can be recieved. That way everybody can know where the template is on your server but cannot access it.